# ValidationError: Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required., content: Path `content` is required

Tags: angular, database, mean-stack, mean

I am trying to make an app that submits text from two input fields in database. It all worked when only submit was there, but when I edited the code to be able to edit my posts, my creation of posts went wrong somewhere and I don't know where. Could anyone help?

CODE:

html

```
<mat-card>
  <!-- <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner> -->
  <form (submit)="onSavePost(postForm)" #postForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        name="title"
        [ngModel] ="post.title"
        required
        minlength="3"
        placeholder="Post Title"
        #title="ngModel"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Please enter a post title.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <input
        matInput
        name="content"
        [ngModel] ="post.content"
        required
        placeholder="Post Content"
        #content="ngModel"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Please enter some content</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Save Post</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Function for submitting the form:

```
onSavePost(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.mode === 'create') {
      this.postsService.addPost(form.value.title, form.value.content);
    } else {
      this.postsService.updatePost(
        this.postId,
        form.value.title,
        form.value.content
      );
    }
    form.resetForm();
  }
}
```

Add and update post functions:

```
addPost(title: string, content: string) {
    const post: Post = { id: null, title: title, content: content };
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; postId: string }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/posts',
        post
      )
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        const id = responseData.postId;
        post.id = id;
        this.posts.push(post);
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }

  updatePost(id: string, title: string, content: string) {
    const post: Post = { id: id, title: title, content: content };
    this.http
      .put('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + id, post)
      .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }
```

So I had older posts, and I could update and delete them, but I can't make new ones. I also have an error "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'" but I imported FormsModule very well! What could be the problem?

Comment: Does `I can't make new ones` mean `this.postsService.updatePost` is executed even `this.mode === 'create'` ?

Comment: Do you import the [MatInputModule](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api)? If not, you should do this in order to get rid of the error you mentioned.

Comment: I did import MatInputModule and it still has an error. And for the first question, I can't tell since I can't create a new post.. I could only update old ones